# I have several errors in pygame and need assistance

Tags: python, pygame

This is my first post so please excuse any errors. I am using Python version 3.8.2 and have had a few errors in my code that I have not been able to figure out. I am using a windows computer. I am new to Python. I have been trying to follow a tutorial on making a Flappy Bird AI. The full code is at the bottom. I thought it would be easier if it was spaced out where I am having errors. Hopefully someone can help me because I am not sure what I am able to do to fix my errors.

When I type in (dir(pygame)) it says unable to initiate device PRN.

I am trying to  get images from files on my C drive. The first error that I have is:

```
    Exception has occurred: error
Couldn't open
"C:\Python\Flapy_bird_ai.py" line 12, in <module>


BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "C:/Python/Flappy.zip/imgs/bird1.png"))), 

pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs","C:/Python/Flappy.zip/imgs/bird2.png,


pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "C:/Python/Flappy.zip/imgs/bird3.png" )))]
```

My other error that I have is:

Module 'pygame' has no 'QUIT' member

Module 'pygame' has no 'quit' member

```
def main():
    bird = Bird(200, 200)
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))

    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: (error here)
                run = False
        bird.move()

        draw_window(win, bird)

    pygame.quit() (error here)
    quit()

main()
```

Here is all my code

```
import pygame
import neat
import os
import random

WIN_WIDTH = 500
WIN_HEIGHT = 800


BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "C:/Python/Flappy.zip/imgs/bird1.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs","C:/Python/Flappy.zip/imgs/bird2.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "C:/Python/Flappy.zip/imgs/bird3.png" )))]
PIPE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "C:/Python/Flappy.zip/imgs/pipe.png")))
BASE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "C:/Python/Flappy.zip/imgs/base.png")))
BG_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "C:/Python/Flappy.zip/imgs/bg.png")))

class Bird:
    IMGS = BIRD_IMGS
    MAX_ROTATION = 25
    ROT_VEL = 20
    ANIMATION_TIME = 5

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tilt = 0
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.vel = 0
        self.height = self.y
        self.img_count = 0
        self.img = self.IMGS[0]

    def jump(self):
        self.vel = -10.5
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.height = self.y

    def move(self):
        self.tick_count += 1

        d = self.vel*self.tick_count + 1.5*self.tick_count**2

        if d >= 16:
            d = 16

        if d < 0:
            d -= 2

        self.y = self.y + d

        if d < 0 or self.y < self.height + 50:
            if self.tilt < self.MAX_ROTATION:
                self.tilt = self.MAX_ROTATION
        else:
            if self.tilt > -90:
                self.tilt -= self.ROT_VEL

    def draw(self, win):
        self.img_count += 1

        if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*2:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*3:
            self.img = self.IMGS[2]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count == self.ANIMATION_TIME*4 + 1:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
            self.img_count = 0

        if self.tilt <= -80:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
            self.img_count = self.ANIMATION_TIME*2

        rotaded_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)
        new_rect = rotaded_image.get_rect(center=self.img.get_rect(topLeft = (self.x, self.y)).center)
        win.blit(rotaded_image, new_rect.topleft)

    def get_mask(self):
        return pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)


def draw_window(win, bird):
    win.blit(BG_IMG, (0, 0))
    bird.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    bird = Bird(200, 200)
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))

    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        bird.move()

        draw_window(win, bird)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

main()
```

Comment: Apart from the syntax error on line 76 (`topleft`, not `topLeft`), this code "works" for me.  (It just shows junk on the window, but does not give the error quoted.)  Are you using some IDE (like PyCharm)?  It looks like PyGame isn't installed correctly.  What happens in a Python console when your just type `import pygame` ?

Comment: @Kingsley I am using Visual Studio Code on Windows. When I typed import pygame in the visual studio terminal it said "import : The term 'import' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1 + import pygame + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (import:String) [], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"  I have no idea what any of this means.

Comment: @Kingsley When I go to the command prompt and I do "pip import pygame" I get "Requirement already satisfied: pygame in c:\python\python download\lib\site-packages (1.9.6)"  link to errors: https://imgur.com/a/4TzyYv7

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't have the reputation to post a comment, so if someone can make this post a comment that would he very helpful.

@Alex, it is `pip install pygame` to install PyGame.
`import pygame` is a Python command that imports the PyGame module that allows you to use PyGame functions.

EDIT: I don't think that PyGame can open zip files as a regular directory either upon further inspection of your errors.

EDIT 2: @Alex, are you using a version of visual studio code that supports Python? VS supports Python out of the box on if it is 2017 or later. (I think)